# How to derive a closed-form optimal solution of the following concave maximization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, closed-form

The following problem

$\max_{x, y} f(x,y) = \log x + \log (x+y) - 2x -3y$

subject to $x \geq 0, y \geq 0$

is a concave maximization problem, and thus can be numerically solved by convex optimization methods. The optimal solution may be $(x^*, y^*) = (1, 0)$.

However, I want to derive the solution analytically.
I tried the following approach, for example, by taking partial derivative,

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x+y} - 2$

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{x+y} - 3$

And there exists no solution that makes both partial derivative to be $0$.

Comment: Indeed. However, what it shows is just that your maximizer, if it exists at all, must be on the boundary.

Comment: What is concave, exactly? The problem or the objective?

Comment: Both of them. The objective function is concave and feasible set is convex, and thus problem is concave maximization problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Elementary solution (no Lagrangian, etc.)

Firstly observe that the objective is concave because it is a sum of concave functions (the concavity of $\log(x+y)$ follows from the concavity of $\log$ and the fact that $x+y$ is affine).

Next, since the derivatives
\begin{align*}
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} &= \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{x+y} - 2\\
   \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} &= \frac{1}{x+y} - 3
\end{align*}
do not vanish simultaneously in the first quadrant ($x,y>0$), the maximum must be attained at the boundary of this set. Therefore the optimal point has $x=0$ or $y=0$. Since $x=0$ can be discarded we are left with a point of the form $(x,0)$. For such points the objective becomes
$$
    g(x) = f(x,0) = 2\log(x) - 2x,
$$
which reaches its maximum when $g'(x)=0$, i.e.,
$$
    \frac{2}{x}-2 = 0.
$$
Hence $x=1$ and the optimal point is $(1,0)$ with optimal value $g(1)=2\log(1)-2=-2$.

Answer (score 0):

What you need for optimisation under constraints are the [Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions), which, for your problem can be written as
$$
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x} \left(x,y,\mu\right)=0\\
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial y} \left(x,y,\mu\right)=0\\
x>0, y\ge0, \mu\ge0\\
y\mu=0\ ,
$$
where $\ \mathcal{L}\ $ is given by
$$
\mathcal{L}\left(x,y,\mu\right)=f(x,y)+\mu y\ .
$$
With $\ \mathcal{L}\ $ thus defined, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x} \left(x,y,\mu\right)&=\frac{1}{x} +\frac{1}{x+y}-2=0\\
\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial x} \left(x,y,\mu\right)&=\frac{1}{x+y}-3+\mu=0\\ .\
\end{align}
From this, bit of elementary algebra gives
$$
x=\frac{1}{\mu-1}\ ,
$$
which implies $\ \mu>1\ $, since $\ x>0\ $, and hence $\ y=0\ $, from the condition $\ \mu y=0\ $.  Substituting $\ y=0\  $ in the first of the above conditions then gives $\ x=1\ $, and thence, $\ \mu=2\ $.

Answer (score 0):

Considering with $$f(x,y) = \ln x+\ln(x+y)- 2x-3y$$ the Lagrangian

$$
L(x,y,\lambda_1,\lambda_2,s_1,s_2) = f(x,y)+\lambda_1(x-s_1^2)+\lambda_2(y-s_2^2)
$$

Here $s_1,s_2$ are slack variables to produce the restrictions $x\ge 0, y\ge 0$

The stationary points are the solutions for

$$
\nabla L = 0 = 
\cases{\frac 1x+\frac{1}{x+y}+\lambda_1 - 2=0\\
\frac{1}{x+y}+\lambda_2-3=0\\
x-s_1^2=0\\
y-s_2^2\\
\lambda_1s_1=0\\
\lambda_2s_2=0
}
$$

giving

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccc}
f & x & y & \lambda_1 & \lambda_2 & s_1^2 & s_2^2\\
 -2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The only real solution is represented by the first numeric row. We can conclude also that the restriction $y \ge 0$ is active because $s_2^2=0$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But, this is a simplified problem. Actually, I want to solve the problem with much more variables. The problem with 2 variables can be solved easily by Lagrangian method with simple manipulations. Then, for problems with more variables, how can I solve the above nonlinear simultaneous equations? Should I apply the newton's method?

Comment: As long as the objective  function ipograph is convex, the maximization problem  can be solved using an interior point method.